# How much would being at a top university at my country help in hypothetically getting into a good US/Europe uni?

Tags: application, university

The question **is** pretty vague, of course. But what I'm trying to get is if that has some influence at all.

To put it into perspective: I'm a Physics undergrad student at University of Campinas, which is, undoubtely, alongside University of São Paulo, the top university at Brazil, likewise South America.

I personally don't really care about rankings, but those are obviously not high-ranked unis **worldwide**, which is not difficult to understand, and a good example of how rankings don't tell you much of the story. It's not even designed to serve such purpose, so, yeah.

What I want to understand is how the academy at US/Europe, or other generally good unis alongside the world look at these ones I've quoted, in the sense of, how much that would influentiate a student's *curriculum*, if he was trying to get into a undergraduate, graduate, masters, PhD (and so on) education. Does it count for much?

Using me as a general example, I would guess that the fact that I'm a South American who probably wouldn't even have the money to go live in another continent at the time I was getting out of HS should be taken to consideration. And, of course, it's not particularly easy to get and stay in those unis that I've cited.

Naturally, the student's grades, projects, or anything intelectually, and maybe academically valuable is probably what matters the most. But this question is focused on the *university* itself.

That's pretty much it, any honest (and substantiated) response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it helps a lot (**Edit:** at least in the US, and I suspect for at least parts of Europe too).  Why?  What do we try to assess in admissions: your preparation and your likelihood of success.  For this, your university record and letters of recommendation are key.

If you are getting great grades in advanced-sounding classes, but from a university nobody has heard of, we won't know how to evaluate the rigour of the program and your preparation.  But if it's one of the top universities in your country, then your transcript will mean a lot more.

Similarly, if you are getting recommendations from strong researchers, especially those who are familiar with research universities in North American and Europe (and this is much more likely to be true of professors at top schools), the letters will have much more weight.

The main problems I have in evaluating many foreign applications are no one on the committee knowing how to interpret transcripts (in my department, there are people can interpret transcripts from top universities in South America) and reading letters that are not very helpful (many faculty at non-research-intensive schools in many countries do not know how to write letters for US grad schools).

Comment: You should add a disclaimer for which country you are answering. E.g., I'd say in Germany it doesn't matter much as long as the degree from their home university is recognized as equivalent to a German degree.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I do not quite understand what you actually mean by "interpreting transcripts", though.

Comment: @Roland Done!  Though I find it hard to imagine it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JohannWagner As I allude to in the 2nd paragraph, we don't know what the standards are for classes listed, e.g. as "Quantum Mechanics" or "Linear Algebra", both in terms of grades assigned and what might have been covered in what level of rigour.  I don't know about within Brazil, but certainly in some countries (including the US) there is wide variation in what is covered at different schools and how  rigorous the grading is.

Comment: Sorry, but this is too optimistic. What you do is much more important than where you do it. If you are a C student at, say, Yale, then you are behind an A- student from almost every other accredited university in the US. And, I think US academics are more sophisticated in evaluation than this suggests. Moreover, the academic community is pretty global these days.

Comment: @Buffy But where you are affects what you do, what we know about what you've done.  I have  done grad admissions many times, and we often find that applicants from smaller, lesser known schools (including accredited schools in the US) have shocking low standards for, say, their Abstract Algebra classes.  Even teaching Calc II, I see this with undergrad transferring in Calc I credit from other schools.

Answer (score 0):

If you do well at a top school and your professors will put their reputations on the line to affirm it then it is a plus. But if you are a mediocre student at a top school you won't get any benefit at all.

What you do dominates where you do it. Just make sure that your accomplishments are known to the faculty and that they are willing to write good letters on your behalf (probably more important in US than elsewhere).

For two students with equal records, one from a "top" place and the other from a more modest institution, there will be a small benefit, but other things could easily dominate that bit of a boost.

This was long ago, but I went to a small, not especially highly ranked, place for undergraduate studies. There was a small faculty in math who didn't do a lot of research. But I was invited to doctoral study at an R1 university due to a conversation between department heads. I doubt that happens any more, but I worked hard and had a good, but not perfect, record. Had I gone to, say, Yale as an undergrad it wouldn't have made much of any different, I think.

However, I seriously (seriously) doubt that having studied in South America will be any disadvantage. Academia is global in these times. Do good work. Get local recognition for it.